# How to strip non-alphanumeric characters, convert spaces to dashes, uppercase to lowercase in this context

Tags: php

I am using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), which is very good.

I am trying to take the output of one of the fields I created and give it the "permalink treatment", that is strip out non-alphanumeric characters like slashes, convert uppercase to lowercase, and convert spaces to dashes.

Specifically I am wanting to do this with the checkbox field. I want to do this, because I want to use the outputted values as css class names.

Its output is called by this bit of PHP (modified slightly from the [documented use](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/), see example #4):

```
<?php

$values = get_field('field_name');
if($values)
{

foreach($values as $value)
{
    echo ' ' . $value;
}

}

?>
```

Which returns all of the checkbox values (5 - 10 in this case) separated by a space. I successfully got the values showing up as class names, but now I need a way to format them to actually work as class names.

How could I tweak this to work? I found this bit that seems to work for a sinlge string:

```
function stripJunk($string){    
    $string = str_replace(" ","-", trim($string));         
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/","", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    return $string;}
```

but in my case it's an array, and I don't know how to work with that. I'm pretty worthless when it comes to PHP, except for being able to tweak things a little bit without breaking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sanitize_html_class()` or `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`. Both functions do almost the same. But note that [much more](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) characters a valid in CSS class names.

Examples: ✂ ✉ ✔✽ ✾ ✿ ❀ ❉ ❤ ❦ ☂ ☔ ☎ ☘ ♫ ♻ ⚥

#### Update

I recommend to encapsulate the code in a [prefixed](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/) function to avoid collisions with poorly written plugin using the same names as you do.

Example (not tested):

```
function wpse_48986_custom_fields_to_classes( $field_name )
{
    $values = get_field( $field_name );

    if ( is_string( $values ) )
    {
        return trim( sanitize_html_class( $values ) );
    }

    if ( is_array( $values ) )
    {
        // Prepare the array values.
        $values = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $values );
        $values = array_map( 'trim', $values );
        return implode( ' ', $values );
    }

    // We didn't get a string or an array.
    return '';
}
```

And when you need the CSS classes somewhere just write:

```
print wpse_48986_custom_fields_to_classes( 'field_name' );
```

I couldn't test the code code: I don't have the plugin installed, and my main computer is broken, so there may be errors. Feel free to edit this post and fix the broken code. :)

Comment: Thank you. I figured WordPress would already have something in place for that. I still can't figure out how to use it in my context, though.

If only I could jack in for a few hours like the Matrix, wake up and say: "I know PHP."

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. I get  a server error when I include that function.

I changed 'field_name' to match my actual field name. I'm not sure what that first $field_name variable is all about.

Comment: I'll see what I can do to get this working.

Comment: Ah, I had a bug in the function. That happens when I cannot work on my server. Fixed (I hope). :)

Comment: Still get the server error whenever that bit is included. I really appreciate the effort and I wish I knew enough to make it work. It's all good, though. If you have time to look into it more, great, if not, it's not a make or break issue.

Comment: What does the error say? _A server error_ is not enough information.

Comment: Sorry, it's a 500 error. The site will not load at all with that function included. http://i.imgur.com/2QOB0.png

Comment: Get the [real PHP error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Some unspecified server error is not fixable.

Comment: Right, right. OK this is the PHP error: 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in ~/wp-content/themes/ht-pet-sass/functions.php on line 134`


line 134 corresponds to the line after 
    `if ( is_string( $values )`

in your fuction.

Comment: Then add the missing bracket. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Hah, well I didn't see that missing parentheses until I looked at the new code and old side by side for a few. My PHP skills are lacking. Works perfectly now. I switched to `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`, though, because the output from `sanitize_html_class()` had no dashes at all, just everything compressed together.

Thanks again!